# SceneKit AVPlayer only audio is playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, scenekit, avplayer

I am trying to play a video in `SceneKit`. I can hear the audio but video is not rendering. The way i am using the scene is as follows. Please help.

```
SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"art.scnassets/plane.scn"];
SCNNode *plane = [scene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"plane" recursively:YES];

AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4"]];
plane.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = player;
[player play];

SCNView *scnView = (SCNView *)self.view;
scnView.scene = scene;
scnView.allowsCameraControl = YES;
scnView.showsStatistics = YES;
scnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a real iPhone not simulator to enjoy.

Another reason is the shading in the material panel should not be physical based. You may try Blinn. The code has no problem.

If using a physical based, you have to add an extra light to make it work.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: I am using physical device

Comment: I got it play well. It’s just in the middle of plane.

Comment: Thanks E.Coms. Changing the lighting model to blinn worked

Answer (score 1):

you can keep PBR and get glass reflections with a non-rough material. use the `emission` instead of `diffuse` for the the video though

```
plane.geometry.firstMaterial.emission.contents = player
```